# How do I configure a xorg.conf to use my monitor's native resolution?

Tags: xorg

I've tried this on my own several ways by reading wiki, and other peoples problems by creating 10-monitor.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, and rebooting i've also tried all repository nvidia drivers, ive also tried editing the xorg.conf in /etc/X11/ but i know im doing something wrong, something simple. I just now did a fresh install of 12.04 and did updates, and restarted, I have no proprietary nvidia drivers in use or a xorg.conf generated. Heres my Xrandr results:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0*
800x600        60.3     56.2
848x480        60.0
640x480        59.9
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I'd like to use the native 16:9 1386x768 60Hz. Heres my results from sudo gtf 1368 768 60

```
# 1368x768 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 47.70 kHz; pclk: 85.86 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then i did

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  85.86  1368 1440 1584 1800  768 769 772 795  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then finally added it

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1368x768_60.00
```

It went there for a sec, then black screened. do i need to create the 10-monitor.conf first or ?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple process, that i figured out by reading other posts to force 16:9, 16:10 resolutions, you do not need to make a 10-monitor.conf or even generate a xorg.conf, or use NVIDIA (recommended drivers). First know your refresh rate. Mine is 60Hz. Magnavox 19inch HD widescreen, with HDMI, VGA, TV outputs. Currently I'm using my VGA output on a NVIDIA 6200 Graphics card running a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 Unity 3D. This will work for anyone stuck in 1024x768 4:3 thats not getting their proper resolution.

Open a terminal, type `sudo xrandr`: all we need from this info is what output your using----> (VGA-1 connected) this one is mine VGA-1. Then pick a resulotion you want say 1280x720 thats a 16:9 720p HD. Then type: cvt 1280 720 60, where i put 60 put your Refresh rate there.`This is what comes back

```
Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
```

Now copy that whole modeline from the first quote till the end, then type `sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync`, nothing should return, then type `sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1280x720_60.00`, the screen should change right then and there and your done. See, i tried this for two days tearing my hair out, but i was only trying 1 resolution 1368x768 which wont even work anyway lol ....then i wake up this morning and thought about it. and googled a true list of all 16:9 resolutions, http://pacoup.com/2011/06/12/list-of-true-169-resolutions/ and started trying these. first one i picked work, the  720p HD....took ten seconds :)

Comment: Would you  care to give more details. Your answer is not very clear